# Skipping the . and .. Directories in DirHandle

Tags: perl, perlscript

How to skipp . and .. directories in DirHandle?

```
use DirHandle;
if (defined $d) {
    while (defined($_ = $d->read)) { print "$_ \n" ; }
 undef $d;
}
```

Comment: `next if /^[.][.]?\z/;`

Comment: What if i want to skip files.?

Answer (score 5):

By the way, don't use `undef $d` — `$d = undef` is preferable.

There are several ways — all of them simple if you know Perl or regular expressions

The obvious

```
while ( defined(my $node  = $d->read) ) {
  next if $node eq '.' or $node eq '..';
  print "$dir\n"; 
}
```

Using a regex

```
while ( defined(my $node  = $d->read) ) {
  next if $node =~ /\A\.\.?\z/;
  print "$dir\n"; 
}
```

or, more tidily but less safely because a Linux directory node can have names like `...` and `....` etc., you can just ensure that the node contains something other than a dot `.`

```
while ( defined(my $node  = $d->read) ) {
  next unless $node =~ /[^.]/;
  print "$dir\n"; 
}
```

Comment: To expand on Borodin's comment, `$d = undef;` sets the var to undefined, while `undef $d;` also frees some memory associated with the scalar, making it more expensive to use that variable again.